# Building formatted strings in C

Tags: c, string, printf

Lets say I have lots of `printf` usage, but I want to store them in a string and print them all in one go. Imagine the case below:

```
printf("%d,", _counter);
printf("IS REAL,", _condition);
printf("%f,", _value);
printf("%d,\r\n", _time);
```

What I want to do is to build a string and use `printf` only once when I am sure that I want to print it on screen. For example the output of above code will be:

```
1,IS REAL,663,1044
```

In C# I would use `StringBuilder`....but how to do this in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, `sprintf` is what you are asking I believe, however, you can always do this:

```
printf("%d, IS REAL(%d), %f, %d,\r\n", _counter, _condition, _value,  _time);
```

and sprintf returns the number of characters written so you can use it like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char buf[256];
    int s = sprintf(buf, "This %d,", 12);
    s += sprintf(buf+s, "and this %f.", 1.0);
    s += sprintf(buf+s, ",also  %f", 2.0);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You use `sprintf()`, or (much better) [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

```
char buffer[32];

snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%d,IS REAL,%f,%d\r\n", _counter, _value, _time);
printf("%s", buffer);
```

I skipped the `_condition` variable access, since that line didn't do any formatting.

Comment: You forgot the `size` in the call to `snprintf`

Comment: Thanks, fixed! This would probably never have happeed in actual code. :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your qeustion, you can add as many formatters or strings as you want.

```
printf("%d,IS REAL,%f,%d,\r\n", _counter, _value, _time);
```

Note, that I ommited this one:

```
printf("IS REAL,", _condition);
```

because you are goiving it as an argument, but didn't specify a format for it, just plain text, so it would be wrong. If you want to print `_condition` as value, then you must add also a format specifier like `%d` or whatever `_condition` is. If it is a boolean you could do something like this:

```
printf(""%s,",  (_condition == 1) ? "IS REAL" : "IS NOT");
```

But I don't know your code, so this is just a suggestion assuming you want something like this done.

If you want to build a string in memory, collecting all the data first, you have to use `s(n)printf`, but then you must make sure to allocate and deallocate enough space for your string.

Answer (score 0):

create a function that takes the current string and the chunk that you want to plug on as arguments,

then malloc a new pointer on char with a length equal to *(strlen(string) + strlen(chunk) + 1)*

you can use **sprintf** let say:

```
sprintf(newstring, "%s%s", string, chunk);
```

then free the last two string if you allocate them manually.

Returns the pointer of the new string.